# Django how to get the values with an id as key and shows it in template

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I have got a DICT like this:

```
{4: {'26.00': "{'tac': {'4.99': '1.30'}}"}, 2: {'32.00': "{'tac': {'4.99': '1.60'}}"}}
```

Where 4 and 2 are the respective user id.

I send the DICT to template and I also have access to the user id in a for loop. Is it possible to get only the data to the respsctive user in the template:

I would like to learn a workout to get the dict data for each user by user.id.

Is it possible to do something like this? Remembering that the DICT isnt inside any model. So it is a static data generated before the tamplate renders.

```
user_name: John
user_email: j@j.com
user_id = 2
amount = 32.00
tac = 4.99 : 1.60   

user_name: Charles
user_email: c@c.com
user_id = 4
amount = 26.00
tac = 4.99 : 1.3
```

Thank you very much for any ideas os directions to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the problem and I hope to help others with this.

What you can do is in your views inside a user loop add data to send to front end inside the user object.

First I added a key for subTotal and taxDict.In this case ussers id's are 4, 2. So my dict looked like this.

```
{4: {'subTotal': '26.00', 'taxDict': "{'tac': {'4.99': '1.30'}}"}, 2: {'subTotal': '32.00', 'taxDict': "{'tac': {'4.99': '1.60'}}"}}
```

Then in the views I did a loop for in the user object:
In the loop for I created (can be na letter or word as variable) in my case 'x'. My dict is in a variable called DATADICT.

```
user = User.objects.filter(is_approved=True)
for u in user:
    u.x = DATADICT[u.id]['subTotal']
```

Then you pass user to template as a context.

```
return render(request, 'home.html', { 'user': user,})
```

And in template you do:

```
{% for u in user %}
{{ u.x }}
{% endfor %}
```

And you will get subTotal data from DATADICT as it was a model field.
In this case:
32.00
26.00

And that is it :-)